# Grammar for a boolean calculator language

Tags: grammar

I am writing a grammar for a boolean calculator language. Programmes written in this language will consist of atmost one statement whose result will be boolean.

An example statement of such language is given below:

```
( A + B >= C ) AND ( D == 4 )
```

The grammar that I have come up with so far is given below:

```
E => T COP T | EXPR BOP EXPR
T => VAR | EXPR
VAR => A | B | C | D
EXPR => AEXPR | CEXPR
AEXPR => "(" VAR AOP VAR ")"
CEXPR => VAR COP AEXPR | AEXPR COP AEXPR
AOP => + | - | * | / | %
BOP => AND | OR
COP => == | != | < | > | <= | >=
```

The main thing to consider here is that no two VARs can be joined in a binary operation `BOP` and that the statement **must** return a boolean.

I want to know if the above grammar satisfies this criteria or am I missing something?

Any help will be appereciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> The main thing to consider here is that no two VARs can be joined in a binary operation BOP and that the statement must  return a boolean.

The above requirement fails in following case:

```
E = EXPR BOP EXPR
EXPR = AEXPR

=> E = AEXPR BOP AEXPR
```

I am assuming here that `(VAR AOP VAR)` yields a `VAR`.

A more standardized form of your required grammar is given below:

```
E = T COP T | EXPR BOP EXPR;
T = VAR | AEXPR;
VAR = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D";
AEXPR = "(" VAR AOP VAR ")" | "(" VAR AOP AEXPR ")";
EXPR = VAR COP AEXPR | AEXPR COP AEXPR;
AOP = "+" | "-" | "*" | "/" | "%";
BOP = "AND" | "OR";
COP = "==" | "!=" | "<" | ">" | "<=" | ">=";
```